# what is the equivalent of gcc's __attribute__((constructor)) in clang?

Tags: ios, c, frameworks, clang, ld

I have just finished porting a decent amount of c-sources to the iOS platform and packaged them as a universal static framework.  I, then, added the framework (not the project) to a sample iOS app in order to test linkage and proper function.  That's when I ran into a humbling problem.

In my attempt to solve the problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23623223/linker-reports-a-different-set-of-undefined-symbols-in-an-ios-static-library-fra), I also came across some symbols that are composed through the heavy use of macros (i HATE those).  Some of those macros use function attributes that are really extensions of gcc rather than of standard C.

Of course I can always add -std=gnu89, but even then, I am not sure it will resolve the original problem of undefined symbols in the static library.

Not only that, I am now worried that my port to iOS of those sources may not be an accurate port and may result in the type of bugs/issues that maybe related to compiler's codeine and/or optimization policies.

If you can share some of your experience/advice in how best to go about that port, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: You should ask a more specific question. What sort of errors are you getting? I use __attribute__((__constructor\_\_)) in clang C programs and it works fine.

Comment: @Richard: thanks.  That's what i was looking for :((\__constructor\__)).  As for the original problem, it is covered here :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23623223/linker-reports-a-different-set-of-undefined-symbols-in-an-ios-static-library-fra

Comment: @Richard : could you post your comment as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2):

From manual testing with clang 8.0, it seems that both `__attribute__((constructor))` and `__attribute__((__constructor__))` work for your purpose.